# What is a field goal in basketball?

Tags: basketball, nba

So recently I have started taking an interest in basketball after picking up a basketball video game for 3 dollars. One thing I have noticed about stats in the game is that I know what pretty much all of them mean but 1, 'field goals'.

So super 'beginner' question, what is a field goal in basketball?

Comment: Without wanting to seem too unhelpful, what wasn't clear about the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_goal_(basketball))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A field goal is any 2 point or 3 point shot. This means any score that is not from the free-throw line: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_goal_(basketball)